# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask, многопоточность

Приложение выводит некоторые данные, подгруженные из интернета списком. Данные подгружаются с помощью AsynkTask.

Если кликнуть по одному из элементов списка, который является группой, то подгрузиться список для данной группы.

Так вот, сама проблема: кликаю по группе, возвращаюсь назад, опять кликаю по группе и тут вылезает вот такой эксепшен:

```
02-25 09:29:52.436: E/AndroidRuntime(311): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception                                                                02-25 09:29:52.455: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class default.MyActivity$ItemAdapter)]
```

Использую адаптер библиотеки `UniversalImageLoader`. После подгрузки и парсинга `json` в `doInBackground` вызывают `notifyDataSetChanged()` в `onPostExecute`.  
Вылезает вышеупомянутый косяк. Неужели `onPostExecute` работает не в основном потоке?

Может стоит без AsyncTask обойтись?

====================================
**UPD**    
Код AsyncTask:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Скачивание данных (тут просто формируется ссылка)
        ReadStringJson rsj = new ReadStringJson(SERVER_URL_1 + SERVER_PATH_2 + SERVER_PATH_3 + GROUP + "&from=" + (from) + "&number=" + number + SERVER_PATH_4 + FILTER);

        try {
            // Парсинг данных
            // Этот метод дополняет списки данных, которые были создаются в активити
            parsingData(rsj.readFromServer());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
             Log.e("IOException: ", ex.toString());
             ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
             Log.e("JSONException: ", ex.toString());
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        adapter.addEnginesNames(names);
        adapter.addEnginesDescriptions(descriptions);
        adapter.addEnginesLogoUrl(logoUrl);
        adapter.addIsGroup(isGroup);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Может что -то в с тредами? С UI может работать только главный поток, если Вы пытаетесь что-то сделать с графическими элементами из background thread то обычно так падает.

Comment: в doInBackground я подгружаю данные и парсю их. В onPostExecute, который, вроде, должен работать с UI я добавляю в адаптер то, что подгрузилось и делаю adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: А вы случайно не модифицируете что-нибудь из неглавного потока?

> Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

Попробуйте в каждом подозрительном месте залогировать текущий thread id.

Comment: Закомментируйте все в onPostExecute. Работает? Или ту же ошибку выдает? И что обозначает загадочная фраза "возвращаюсь назад"?

Comment: В doInBackground происходит загрузка и парсинг данных, после чего в onPostExecute я обновляю адаптер. Вроде, все так и должно быть, разве нет?

Comment: покажи лучше код адаптера и потока

Comment: @Аня Кайгородова, "ворзвращаюсь назад" означает, что перехожу в предыдущую активити.     
Добавил код AsyncTask

Answer (score 4):

Причина такой ошибки одна и таже - `notifyDataSetChanged()` нужно вызывать сразу, как только данные изменятся. В свое время я специально смотрел сорцы андроида - эта ошибка возникает только в одном случае - если при попытке обновить отображения списка, закешированное значение размера списка и фактическое, полученное от адаптера не совпадают. То есть, если просто модифицировать один элемент, но кол-во элементов не поменяется - эта ошибка не возникнет (ну как минимум до api 14 - которое я смотрел).

Как лечить. Если у Вас есть модификация списка (например добавили один элемент) - сразу, следующей строкой вставляйте `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Единственное исключение - данные загружаются в цикле - тогда вставляйте сразу по выходу с цикла. Но если в цикле есть `return` или подобное (например может быть исключение), то желательно в `try - finally` завернуть.

Если используете адаптер, наследованный от `ArrayAdapter` - то там все проще - он сам все дергает. Рекомендую его [посмотреть](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java).

На первых порах лучше поставить на один `notifyDataSetChanged()` больше, чем гадать.

---

В Вашем случае, если данные подгружаются каким то методом, то `notifyDataSetChanged()` должен быть в следующей строке. И проследите, что бы он всегда **гарантированно** вызывался.

Comment: Добавил кода. Если я Вас правильно понял, то notifyDataSetChanged() нужно делать непосредственно в doInBackground.. интересно-интересно, сейчас опробую

Comment: Так нельзя делать. Получите пачку новых приключений. Адаптер нужно изменять в ui потоке.

Если же Вам нужно добавить 100500 записей и без этого не можете жить (ну всякое бывает), тогда используйте [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Накопили 10-20 записей - вызвали. В обработчике перенесли в адаптер записи.

Comment: В примере кода, который привел как раз notifyDataSetChanged() в основном потоке. Так правильно, так ведь?

Comment: Это похоже на правду.

перечитал вопрос,

 >> Так вот, сама проблема: кликаю по группе, возвращаюсь назад, опять кликаю по группе и тут вылезает вот такой эксепшен:

а случайно ссылка на адаптер не статическая? Или может где то ее кешируете. Тогда такая ситуация вполне может быть. Грубо говоря, из за статических ссылок (да и вообще, если неправильно написать), выходит, что после возвращения с второй активити основная то обычно пересоздается, а старая не удаляется полностью и висит в памяти.

Comment: Сначала ссылка была статическая. Убрал статик. Теперь при таком же кейсе выпадает 
>java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 4

Подгрузился список, кликнул на один из элеметов-групп. Зашел в него (в группе 4 подгруженных элемента). Возвращаюсь к исходному списку и жму на следующий элемент-группу(он как раз 6-ой). Выпадет эксепшн.
Почему-то не пересоздалась основная активити?

Comment: а кто его знает, как там код написан.